# Hide all <li> elements except one in nav bar

Tags: html, css

I am not entirely sure this is possible with CSS, but I know it is with Jquery. If it is possible only with CSS, I would appreciate help that way as I don't understand Jquery at all.

I am looking to make a breakpoint at 800px. I need to hide all the li items except the logo at this breakpoint.. How do I make an exception the to logo, which is an li item as well?

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
ul,
li,
span {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0 0 14px 0;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.wht {
  color: #fff;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
/*Vivid Page Settings*/

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: #000 1px solid;
}
.vd-hide {

 display: none;
  
}
.vd-settings-wrapper {
  width: 15%;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.vd-user-settings {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 12px 2px 0 21px;
}
.vd-currency-selector {
  width: 58px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 12px 2px 1px 2px;
}
.vd-language-selector {
  width: 58px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 3px 2px 0 2px;
}
/*Vivid Main Navigation*/

.vd-navigation-wrapper {

 display: flex;
}

.vd-nav-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 75%;
  height: 78px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.vd-nav-wrapper ul {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  /* text-align: center; */
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.vd-nav-wrapper li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.vd-nav-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 18px 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.vd-logo-img {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
/*Vivid Checkout Settings*/

.vd-cart-wrapper {
  width: 10%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.vd-cart-selector {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: -11px 31px 0 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  right: -9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vd-navigation-wrapper">
     <div class="vd-settings-wrapper">
     <div class="vd-user-settings">
        </div>
        <div class="vd-currency-selector">
        </div>
        <div class="vd-language-selector">
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="vd-nav-wrapper">
   <ul>
    <li>Shop</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li class="vd-logo-img"><img src="img/vivid_logo.png"/></li>
    <li>Lookbook</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
   </ul>
     </div>
      <div class="vd-cart-wrapper">
       <div class="vd-cart-selector"></div>
      </div>
      
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the selector you need. I think it's self explanatory:

```
.vd-navigation-wrapper  li:not(.vd-logo-img) {
  display: none;
}
```

**Edit** Thanks to Hajji Tark for pointing out Edge and FF do not support `:not()` selector. The workaround is to set `display:none` for all `li`s and override it for the exception:

```
.vd-navigation-wrapper li {
  display: none;
}
.vd-navigation-wrapper .vd-logo-img {
  display: block; /* use inline-block or list-item if appropriate */ 
}
```

Haven't understood your `@media` queries requirements. Let me know if you need help with those. Basically you need to wrap it in a

```
@media (min-width: 800px) { /* rules here */ }
```

or

```
@media (max-width: 800px) { /* rules here */ }
```

If you want a specific case for `800px` (equal to), you can use

```
@media (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 800px){ /* rules here */ }
```

Comment: Chrome : No support
Edge: No support
Firefox : No support

Comment: Great Answer. Thank you!

Comment: @HajjiTarik You are mistaking [`selector list argument of :not()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-not-sel-list) of CSS4 with the [`:not()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) single selector of CSS3. My initial answer was perfectly fine (98.19% browser support).

Answer (score 1):

`@media only screen and ( max-width: 800px ) {
    li[class!="vd-logo-img"] { display: none; }
}`

`Media Queries`
Here, I used the CSS media queries to determine the  page document current size, if it gets to 800px, then the styles will be applied to the document.

`Selector`
I used the attribute selector to target all the `<li>` element excluding the `<li class="vd-logo-img">` with a class equal to "vd-logo-img"

Comment: Great usage of `CSS` selectors! Welcome to SO! +1. I would drop the `only screen` though (hasn't been requested), right? And I'm not sure `!=` would still work if the element would also have a second class. Tip: you can prefix code lines with 4 spaces to make a multi-line code block.

Comment: Thanks and Copied.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
.vd-navigation-wrapper  li {
     display: none;
}

.vd-navigation-wrapper  li.vd-logo-img {
     display: block;
}
```

This is possible because CSS applies the more restrictive rule.

Answer (score 0):

In your Css:

```
.vd-nav-wrapper li { display: none )
.vd-logo-img { display: initial }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css media query and :not() trick to hide all li without the logo. 
See the css section. [Live On Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6embw1u/) works fine on every browser.

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
ul,
li,
span {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 0 14px 0;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.wht {
  color: #fff;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}


/*Vivid Page Settings*/

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: #000 1px solid;
}

.vd-hide {
  display: none;
}

.vd-settings-wrapper {
  width: 15%;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.vd-user-settings {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 12px 2px 0 21px;
}

.vd-currency-selector {
  width: 58px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 12px 2px 1px 2px;
}

.vd-language-selector {
  width: 58px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 3px 2px 0 2px;
}


/*Vivid Main Navigation*/

.vd-navigation-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.vd-nav-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 75%;
  height: 78px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.vd-nav-wrapper ul {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  /* text-align: center; */
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.vd-nav-wrapper li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.vd-nav-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 18px 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.vd-logo-img {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}


/*Vivid Checkout Settings*/

.vd-cart-wrapper {
  width: 10%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.vd-cart-selector {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: -11px 31px 0 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  right: -9px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {
 .vd-nav-wrapper ul li:not(.vd-logo-img){
display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="vd-navigation-wrapper">
  <div class="vd-settings-wrapper">
<div class="vd-user-settings">
</div>
<div class="vd-currency-selector">
</div>
<div class="vd-language-selector">
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="vd-nav-wrapper">
<ul>
  <li>Shop</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li class="vd-logo-img"><img src="img/vivid_logo.png" /></li>
  <li>Lookbook</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
  </div>
  <div class="vd-cart-wrapper">
<div class="vd-cart-selector"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```